# Why would a US passport photo that passes the travel.state.gov photo tool test be rejected by the actual USCIS system?

Tags: image-quality, scanning

I need to upload a digital US passport-style photo to my online account at USCIS. When I upload my photo there it gets rejected **by the system**.

It says:

> "Your photo did not pass photo requirements. You should upload a new
> photo that meets the 2x2 photo requirements listed on this page."

However, my photo **did pass** "the test" when I uploaded it to the [TSG Photo Tool](https://tsg.phototool.state.gov/photo), which is, I believe, the official site/tool to check the eligibility of a photo. On top of that, they **do suggest** checking the photo on that website too, so it is not just my belief.

Other than that, I did not use any foreign characters when I named the file, and the size of the file also was okay. So, I have a hard time understanding why it got rejected.

Any comments and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should take your photo to your local USCIS office to ask them why it was rejected.  Even if it meets all passport photo requirements, they may have other requirements.  No one here can tell you why your photo has been rejected because 1) We're not the officials responsible for approving the photos.  2) We haven't even seen your photo.

Comment: @xiota Your comment makes sense but I don’t want to provide my personal photo, could provide specific details if someone asks. My only “hope” is to reach out to someone who had experienced a similar issue and/or someone knowing some deficiencies of the tool that I mentioned. Nevertheless, reaching out to my local USCIS office is a good idea. Thanks.

Comment: "its digital copy was not provided to me and I scanned it in a scanner at 600 dpi" – That may be your problem.  They probably want originals.  However, you need to confirm with USCIS if that's the case.

Comment: The size of the head needs to be in a specific range also.

Comment: I know this question is related to photography, but it might actually be better suited to [travel.stackexchange.com](https://travel.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer to my question.

I got the original copy of my digital photo from another store and the photo worked. As far as I know, it is not super easy to get digital copies of passport photos in the US from stores. Some of them simply say no for providing digital copies, some do it by making you purchase their usb flash drive doubling the charge provided that they have their usb drives available at the moment, and a few of them do not charge that much, so one needs to check carefully.

Other observations: Having printed copies of passport photos and scanning them may not work even if it passes the online tool suggested. Also not all stores are very reliable in terms of the image quality, so this probably depends on the photographer. So one should make sure to get passport photos from places which check and verify conditions. They probably claim their photos satisfy the conditions, but my experience showed me it may not be the case.

Answer (score 0):

I have had success just using my phone to take the picture and using their tool to crop it, etc. Sometimes it takes multiple tries and you have to make sure it's the right file type, etc., but it's free.